# Android Animation doesn't work in Timer Task

Tags: android, animation, timer

Hi I am working with android.I had created an override pending transition animation in  my app from left to right successfully using the code

```
   Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
```

Now I am looking to execute this process after a time interval so that i used the Timer function as follows

```
     Timer timer = new Timer();
     timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);

        }

     }, 10000);
```

But in this case the activity will appear, but the animation doesn't work.It worked in the 1st case. I don't know why this happens?? please help me Thanks in advance :)

Comment: any error message in your logCat? it might be because of not running on main thread...

Answer (score 3):

Do it in ui thread

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            });

        }

    }, 10000);
```

**OR try this**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
            }
        }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do needs to be run on the UI/Main thread. A `TimerTask`, which implements `Runnable`, will  attempt to send your intent from it's own thread and is why (I suspect) you're unable to start your activity from inside your `TimerTask`. You should be able to fix this by using a `Runnable` that you start from your activity using the runOnUiThread method.

```
Runnable runStuff = new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
        //your code here
    }
};

runOnUiThread(runStuff);
```

If you need to run this multiple times or on a delay you can use a `Handler` with postDelayed to run your `Runnable` after a fixed amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have enabled the Show animations option in developers menu. Otherwise you may not see them.